# What's the most efficient way of filtering a string with numbers at the end (e.g. foo12)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

Here's a self-thought up quiz very similar to a real life problem that I'm facing.

Say I have a list of strings (say it's called `stringlist`), and among them some have two digit numbers attached at the end. For example, "foo", "foo01", "foo24".

I want to group those with the same letters (but with different two digit numbers at the end).

So, "foo", "foo01", and "foo24" would be under the group "foo".

However, I can't just check for any string that begins with "foo", because we can also have "food", "food08", "food42".

There are no duplicates.

It is possible to have numbers in the middle. Ex) "foo543food43" is under group "foo543food"

Or even multiple numbers at then end. Ex) "foo1234" is under group "foo12"

Most obvious solution I can think of is having a list of numbers.

```
numbers = ["0", "1", "2", ... "9"]
```

Then, I would do

```
grouplist = [[]] //Of the form: [[group_name1, word_index1, word_index2, ...], [group_name2, ...]]
for(word_index=0; word_index < len(stringlist); word_index++) //loop through stringlist
    for(char_index=0; char_index < len(stringlist[word_index]); char_index++) //loop through the word
        if(char_index == len(stringlist[word_index])-1) //Reached the end
            for(number1 in numbers)
                if(char_index == number1) //Found a number at the end
                    for(number2 in numbers)
                        if(char_index-1 == number2) //Found another number one before the end
                            group_name = stringlist[word_index].substring(0,char_index-1)
                            for(group_element in grouplist)
                                if(group_element[0] == group_name) //Does that group name exist already? If so, add the index to the end. If not, add the group name and the index.
                                    group_element.append(word_index)
                                else
                                    group_element.append([stringlist[word_index].substring(0,char_index-1), word_index])
                     break //If you found the first number, stop looping through numbers
                            break //If you found the second number, stop looping through numbers
```

Now this looks messy as hell. Any cleaner way you guys can think of?
Any of the data structures including the final result's can be what you want it to be.

Comment: I would read more about [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and how they can be translated to [finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Read also about [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) & [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a map that maps the group-name to a list of all String of the corresponding group.

Here my approach in java:

```
public Map<String, List<String>> createGroupMap(Lust<String> listOfAllStrings){
  Map<String, List<String>> result= new Hashmap<>();
  for(String s: listOfAllStrings){
    addToMap(result, s)
  }
}

private addToMap(Map<String, List<String>> map, String s){
  String group=getGroupName(s);
  if(!map.containsKey(group))
    map.put(group,new ArrayList<String>();
  map.get(group).add(s);
}

private String getGroupName(String s){
  return s.replaceFirst("\\d+$", "");
}
```

Maybe you can gain some speed by avoiding the RegExp in `getGroupName(..)` but you need to profile it to be sure that an implementation without RegExp would be faster.

Comment: This is what I wanted (except that the regular expression is slightly different from what I was asking, but that's trivial). Can anyone help me explain the complexity difference between this answer and my "just loop everything" answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the string into 2 parts like this.

```
pair<string, int> divide(string s) {
int r = 0;
if(isdigit(s.back())) {
    r = s.back() - '0';
    s.pop_back();
    if(isdigit(s.back())) {
        r += 10 * (s.back() - '0');
        s.pop_back();
    }
}
return {s, r}
```

}